# How do I access the inner data in this Google Custom Search errors array?

Tags: json, google-custom-search

I have a web app using Google Custom Search via REST. So far, everything works fine, but when I exceed the allotted daily quota of queries, I want to give the user some info about it. I get this JSON response, and I can access the "code" and "message" data using response.error.code and response.error.message, but I don´t know how to access the subset "errors", specifically "reason".

I know this is a JSON question, but I don´t have much experience with it. 
This is the JSON structure I receive (which is what I expect)

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "dailyLimitExceeded",
    "message": "This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=323544036192 to enable billing.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=323544036192"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This API requires billing to be enabled on the project. Visit https://console.developers.google.com/billing?project=323544036192 to enable billing."
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution trying different things. I think I got lucky.

```
console.log(response.error.errors[0].reason);
```

This gives me the data I was trying to access.